# Bind existing data frame with variable logic in R

Tags: r

I have a below Input data frame **df** and a variable n

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2 30
2  1  3 10
3  2  5 40
4  3  4 20
5  4  5 30
```

Based on my **n**  value. I need to append that many rows with the existing data frame.
Eg. If n = 5 . I want to append the below values in that manner to my existing data frame

```
1 1 0
2 2 0
3 3 0
4 4 0
5 5 0
```

So My Final Expected output will be

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2 30
2  1  3 10
3  2  5 40
4  3  4 20
5  4  5 30
6  1  1  0
7  2  2  0
8  3  3  0
9  4  4  0
10 5  5  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
n <- 5
ndata <- data.frame(
    V1 = 1:n,
    V2 = 1:n,
    V3 = rep(0, n)
)

rbind(df, ndata)
```